# Specifying context object names of generic views

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I'm having a hard time setting the context object names for django's generic class based views.

```
class FictiveCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    context_object_name = 'fictive_form'
    form_class = forms.FictiveForm
    template_name = 'fictive/create_fictive.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(generic.CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print context
```

I thought setting `context_object_name = 'fictive_form'` would change the name of the context object.
Turns out it just gives an empty object :

```
{'fictive_form': None, 'form': <fictive.forms.FictiveForm object at 0x7f925807a9d0>, u'view': <fictive.views.FictiveCreateView object at 0x7f925807aa50>}
```

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

The `context_object_name` is there for your Model

```
class FictiveCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    context_object_name = 'fictive_form'
    form_class = forms.FictiveForm
    template_name = 'fictive/create_fictive.html'
    model = YourModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(generic.CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print context
```

In your template, `fictive_form`is now a object of YourModel

Comment: Nope, fictive_form is still None. I don't see why a CreateView would require a model anyway. Using the form context variable works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why django's `context_object_name` doesn't work in this case, but this is not a big deal as you can simply handle this by renaming the `form` context variable as below.

```
class FictiveCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    context_object_name = 'fictive_form'
    form_class = forms.FictiveForm
    template_name = 'fictive/create_fictive.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(generic.CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # rename the form context variable
    context[context_object_name] = context.pop('form')
    # return the context dictionay 
    return context
```